# How to give a particular use's privileges to another user in Debian?

Tags: debian, file-permissions, sudo, sudoers, visudo

Lets say in my Debian PC have 2 users called cat and dog.

I want to use `sudo` setup to give dog's privileges to cat. So cat can do what dogs do.

I'm new to sudo stuff but I tried below config. It gives below error when cat trying to access dog's file.

Config:

```
cat ALL=(dog) ALL
```

Error:

```
Sorry, user cat is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/vim /home/dog/test.txt' as root on debian.
```

test.txt file permissions are `rw-r--r--`

Can someone help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the problem.

When you giving privileges from other then the `root` user, then you need to specify user at the `sudo` command.

See below example:

This command run by `cat` and it works.

```
sudo -u dog vim /home/dog/test.txt
```